# Preemptive caching with Nginx

Tags: caching, nginx

How to make a preemptive cache with nginx?

Currently, the cache becomes stale and unloads lots of images at once.

In my http section I have

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:1 keys_zone=zone:10m;
```

In my server configuration I have something like

```
server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name myservername

  root /myapp/public;

  client_max_body_size 2G;

  proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
  proxy_cache_valid      200 301 302 304 1M;
  proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_cache            zone;
  gzip_static on;

  try_files $uri @app;

  location @app {
    if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)\?[0-9]+$") {
      expires max;
      break;
    }

    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    proxy_buffers 8 64k;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://myupstream;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should be more specific with your question. It will be a good idea to provide your nginx config file.

Comment: @EugZol oh, sorry, fix it. This configuration cache images on 1 month